# How to sort array and remove duplicate values with PHP

Tags: php

I have array A :

**Input**:

```
A ={2,3,2,1,3,2,0,3,2,0,11,7,9,2}
```

I want output to be Array B

**Output**:

```
B={0,1,2,3,7,9,11}
```

Comment: Hint: [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: _number increase sort_ -- what does that mean? Do you mean _sort numbers in increasing order_?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends are: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

With these functions you can create the distinct list and sort it:

```
$a = {2,3,2,1,3,2,0,3,2,0,11,7,9,2}
$b = array_unique($a, SORT_NUMERIC)
sort($b, SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter/sort by distinct number values and order ascending..

Unique values:
[Select only unique array values from this array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340450/select-only-unique-array-values-from-this-array)

Order values:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all unique values and then sort them.
`array_unique()` removes all duplicate values.
`sort()` sorts your values from low to high.

```
$B = array_unique($A);
sort($B);
```

Comment: `sort` returns a boolean, not a new array. Its argument has to be a variable, not an expression, because it takes a reference.

Comment: @Barmar You're absolutely right. I posted my answer a bit to fast. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove duplicate values from array using array_unique
$unique_array = array_unique($a);
//sort the resulting array
sort($unique_array);
//dump it to verify
var_dump($unique_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

A ={2,3,2,{1},3,2,{0},3,2,0,11,7,9,{2}}
I want output to be Array B

Output:

B={0,1,2,3,7,9,11}